# sql query to delete by category

Tags: sql, sqlite

ok guys, may be it's not the best title for my problem. so this is the case
i have 2 table in my database,

Parent table

```
---------
 id name 
---------
 0   A
 1   B
 2   C
```

Child table

```
-------------------------
 id   name    parent_id
-------------------------
 0   child_A    1
 1   child_B    0
 2   child_C    2
```

so if record **A** in parent table deleted, how can i delete all child who have parent_id  **0**  (A have id 0) ??

i hope you can understand my problem and help me .. :) thanks in adv .. :)

i think i've got the solution, first i try to get all field that not have parent anymore
by this query

```
SELECT * FROM folders C where  NOT EXISTS (select * from folders as A INNER JOIN gis_folders as B on (A.parent_id = B.id) where A.id= C.id )
```

now i just have to delete all the rows on result from that query .. :)

Comment: Is the table called `Parent` or `gis_folders`?

Comment: You mentioned in a comment that you have recursive folder. How would this relationship be modelled in the database?

Answer (score 2):

This is called a cascading delete.  When you set up the foreign keys you can specify that child rows are deleted.

See section 4.3 of http://www.sqlite.org/foreignkeys.html for more details.

Comment: nice. thanks for your info. but the bad condition is i can't change my database schema to give it foreign key. any idea ?

Answer (score 1):

Do this if you don't have a foreign key set up

```
DELETE parent, child 
FROM parent LEFT JOIN child ON parent.id = child.parent_id 
WHERE parent.id = 0
```

Comment: thanks for your query. but if this parent is like a folder. so in a folder may there some folder again and file (child). so how can if i delete one folder(parent) all folder and file(child) inside that folder will be deleted (because the parent have been deleted)  ?

Comment: I am not quite following what your asking can you post example in your question? Because the way your question was asked, this will do exactly that

Comment: okey i have structure like this
`parent_A
-----parent_B
-----------parent_C
-----------------child_A
-----------child_B
-----child_C
`
so if i delete parent_A, how can all parents and child inside it will be deleted too .. thanks Kris

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way is to create a trigger on deleted of parent A
and there you can get the deleted parent id and  write query to delete from B 
similarly create a trigger on delete of Parent B and there again get id from deleted row and delete all rows from C

Answer (score 0):

Othere way could be create a procedure take a id of parent A as parameter

now writer query like

delete from C where Cid in (select Cid from c where CparentID in (select Bid from B where BparentID = aid))

delete from B where BparentID = aid

delete from A where aid = aid

you can also refere to this

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa933119%28SQL.80%29.aspx

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE TABLE tblparent(
    id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY auto_increment,
    name VARCHAR(50)
)engine=innodb;


CREATE TABLE tblchild(
    id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY auto_increment,
    name VARCHAR(50),
    parent_id INTEGER,
    FOREIGN KEY(parent_id) REFERENCES tblparent(id) ON DELETE CASCADE
)engine=innodb;
```

In that case, when the parent row is deleted, all the rows on the referenced child table that referred on that id will also deleted.

That is called cascading delete.